# Spark on EC2 Dedicated Tenancy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spark-ec2

I have successfully managed to install a Spark Cluster in EC2 using the distribution from:

```
https://github.com/amplab/spark-ec2
```

However, I can see there is no option for having EC2 dedicated hardware tenancy for the Spark master and cluster nodes, is that the case or am I missing something? Will it always run on shared hardware?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the easiest way to accomplish what you are looking for is to set the instance tenancy attribute on a VPC in your account to "dedicated". Then everything you run in that VPC will use dedicated instances.